# pandas_datareader throwing error when requesting multiple cryptocurrency datasets in single request

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

If I make a call for only one cryptocurrency it works, but for multiple it fails.

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
...
crypto_df = pdr.DataReader('BTC-USD', data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2015-01-01')
```

works fine

```
crypto_df = pdr.DataReader('ETH-USD', data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2015-01-01')
```

also works fine

```
crypto_df = pdr.DataReader(['BTC-USD', 'ETH-USD'], data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2015-01-01')
```

fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 199, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 376, in DataReader
    return YahooDailyReader(
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 258, in read
    df = self._dl_mult_symbols(self.symbols)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 285, in _dl_mult_symbols
    result = concat(stocks, sort=True).unstack(level=0)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 7349, in unstack
    result = unstack(self, level, fill_value)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 417, in unstack
    return _unstack_frame(obj, level, fill_value=fill_value)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 444, in _unstack_frame
    return _Unstacker(
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 118, in __init__
    self._make_selectors()
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 167, in _make_selectors
    raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape")
```

This works as expected with stocks, but fails with cryptocurrency.

I'm confident this is not an issue on my side, but I am hoping someone can confirm. I will open a ticket with the developers if this is an unknown bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the index you want to fetch.

```
#Trying to fetch crypto data from yahoo
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
tickers = ['BTC-USD', 'ETH-USD']
crypto_data = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers:
  crypto_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source ='yahoo', start= '2020-12-01')['Adj Close']
```

You are missing `['Adj Close']` in this case.